# Angular 8 and jquery-select-areas plugin not working - .selectAreas is not a function

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, angular8

I am trying to integrate [jquery-select-areas](https://github.com/360Learning/jquery-select-areas) plugin within the Angular 8 project, jQuery is working fine but I am not able to get the plugin working. I have added select area Javascript directly into the project and have modified a as needed, please see below -

```
"styles": [
              "src/assets/styles/styles.scss",
              "src/assets/styles/jquery-select-area/jquery.selectareas.css",
              "src/assets/styles/jquery-select-area/jquery.selectareas.ie8.css"
            ],
            
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "src/assets/jquery/jquery.selectareas.min.js"
            ]
```

And this is how I am trying to use inside the `ngInit` method of angular component -

```
jQuery(function() { 
      console.log("here i am ...");
      $("#ImageViewer").selectAreas({
        minSize: [30, 30],    // Minimum size of a selection
        maxSize: [400, 300],  // Maximum size of a selection
        onChanged: myfunction,    // fired when a selection is released
        onChanging: myfunction2   // fired during the modification of a selection
      }).click(function(){
        alert("Wass up!");
        
      });
   });
```

Error that I am getting is - ***"jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__(...).selectAreas is not a function"*** Please see below console screenshot

[image: console error screenshot selectAreas is not a function]

Can anyone please guide me on how to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone can please throw some light?